# Is it possible to pass a hash table as a variable in AzureDevops from one agent phase to another

Tags: variables, azure-devops, hashtable

I've seen this question pop up a few times in forums, but I have yet to see an answer.  I'm trying to create a variable of a hashtable in one task of an agent phase and pass it to another with powershell.  Specifically I'm trying to build a hashtable variable in one task and pass it to an ARM Template in the next as a secureobject parameter.

The only "answer" I've see is to use the write-output method like this:

Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVariable]$VariableValue"

Which seems to work just fine if I'm trying to create a variable of a STRING.  But I cannot seem to get this to work for an object.  Specifically a hashtable.  I have however been very successful in creating a variable of $(MyHashtable) with a value of "System.Collections.Hashtable" sadly this is not my goal.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are strings, not objects, end of story. You can't pass an object between phases. Phases may run on different agents, and the agents may be on totally different operating systems with different software configurations. Strings are guaranteed to be portable between them.

This means you need to serialize and deserialize non-string values in a portable format, such as JSON. In PowerShell, `ConvertTo-Json -Compress` is what you're after.

Comment: Thank You!  I was looking for a definitive answer and now I have it.  I can start looking towards other options.  Thanks again!